# Symfony2 how to copy one object value to other

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two doctrine objects, where one is the temporary object i need to move all the values to the original object

```
$orgObject = $em->getRepository('Acme:demo')->get($id);
$tempObjec = new demo();
```

How can i copy one value to other, this is just scenario i am saying

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$tempObjec = clone $orgObject;
```

If you have linked object you may [define the method __clone of your class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php):

```
public function __clone()
{
    // ...
}
```